# How can I route the same path for mobile & PC in Nodes.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mobile, router

I want to do a mobile detection in express, make mobile and PC module totally independent, but keep the URL same, which means I cannot redirect a path to /mobile/... just because of the request is from mobile device.

Here is what do in app.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res){
    var ua = req.header('user-agent');
    if(/mobile/i.test(ua)) {
        console.log('user agent is mobile');
        mobileRouter.set(app);
    } else{
        console.log('user agent is pc');
        pcRouter.set(app);
    }
})
```

And in pcRouter.js:

```
var index = require('./pc/index');
var user = require('./pc/user');
var auth = require('./pc/auth');

module.exports.set = function(app) {
    console.log('define pc router');
    app.use('/', index);
    app.use('/user',  user);
    app.use('/auth', auth);
}
```

In pc/index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('pc index');
    res.render('index', { title: 'PC' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I request the home page, terminal only shows these two logs:
'user agent is pc ' and 
'define pc router'

pc/index.js is not being executed, I guess it's because router must be defined at the app.js been started, but how can I realize what I said before:

Same URL route by user agent detection, and keep the mobile sub app & pc sub app totally independent

Comment: What's the difference between the mobile and non-mobile routes? Just the template used or ?

Comment: layout and maybe the page flow

Comment: Express middleware (`use`) and routes should be defined before a request is received, not after. Even if this did work, you would probably experience issues with concurrency. Instead, use your mobile detection middleware to set something like `req.mobile = true` that is then evaluated by your route handlers.

Comment: thank you Kevin, as you say: routes must be defined before a request is recevied, that means i cannot separate mobile module and pc module to totally independent, so sad